# ContentProviders: UserDictionary.Words Permission

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve some data from  UserDictionary.Words db, but my **cursor keeps being retrieved with empty rows**.
I gave the right permissions at the manifest file:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.developer.p402_contentpeovisers">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, UserDictionary.Words.WORD};
    Cursor cursor =
            resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String word = cursor.getString(1);
            // do something meaningful
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

I added some words directly from the emulator **(Settings -> Languages & Input -> Personal dictionary. And then I clicked on plus and I added words)**, and I can see that the words were indeed added  (as you can see in the attatched files). In addition, To be sure, I checked it out by using **adb pull** and sqlite, and I see that the db indeed was updated, when I enterd the words directly from the emulator (attatched).

I've been told I need to add permissions at runtime, and I can't understand the reason for this..? neither the book I study nor Android Developers site mention nothing about permissions on runtime.

**P.S:** 
I'm using:
compileSdkVersion: 25 
minSdkVersion: 16 
targetSdkVersion: 25

**References:** 
[List of words - emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDoM.png)  
[List of words - sqlite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcWLy.png)  

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to search the internet i.e. https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=android+runtime+permission ? The first result https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html gives you the anwer. May be your study book is older than android-6

Comment: I checked it out, and I see that reading user dictionary db is not defined as a dangerous permission, so, I don't need to define a permission at runtime.
And I also checked it, by writing Manifest.permission in the code, and there is no such permission for reading/writing user dictionary.
So why it's not working?

Comment: Can you read it on your device using the android app https://github.com/k3b/ContentProviderHelper/ which is available at [fdroid-appstore](https://f-droid.org/app/de.k3b.android.contentproviderhelper) ?